# Use of unresolved identifier FIRDatabase when using Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, xcode8

I am trying to use the Firebase database. I was watching a tutorial on how to use Firebase and wrote this line of code, `FIRDatabase.database().reference()`. Then I got an error saying, Use of unresolved identifier FIRDatabase. I don't know what is wrong I imported Firebase and FirebaseDatabase.

My Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.2'

target 'FirebaseDatabase' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for FirebaseDatabase

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'

end
```

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact your target has the same name as the Firebase Database module.

Comment: Did you import the framework at the top of your `.swift` file after installing/updating the pod? Also make sure you're using the `.xcworkspace` file and NOT the `.xcodeproj`file. If you've done all that and it's still not recognizing, a lot of times after installing/updating a pod I have to clean and build and then the project will recognize the framework.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes I have done all of those things, let me try clean and building.

Comment: Tried cleaning, still is not working

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 4,**

Write this command in your pod file.

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Then import in your ViewController like this

```
import FirebaseDatabase
```

Full structure of ViewController code like this

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for me Xcode 8.3, Swift 3, this works:

`import FirebaseDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new project with a completely different name (@Callam). It seems that Xcode did not recognize the framework.